# How do I return two values from a function?

Tags: c++, function, function-prototypes

How do I design a function prototype that would allow a single function to find and return simultaneously both the lowest and the highest values in an array? Thank you.

Comment: Return a struct of two numbers, or an std::pair.

Comment: Can  use an array (eg. either pass the array to the function or defined globally).

Comment: Custom struct for return is messy. I prefer void func(int* low_out, int* high_out);

Comment: @rkm_Hodor: That only covers C; there are much better options in C++.

Comment: @Inisheer: Again, return through pointer is reasonable C idiom, but terrible C++ code.

Comment: @ShadowRanger Yup. That's why it's left in the comments... and why I stick with C ;)

Answer (score 16):

`std::pair` covers returning two values, [`std::tuple`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple) generalizes to any number of values. And with `std::tuple`'s [`std::tie` utility function](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/tie), the caller can receive the results into separate variables too, avoiding the need to extract them one by one, for example:

```
std::tuple<int, int> returns_two() 
{
  return std::make_tuple(1, -1);
}

int main() {
  int a, b;

  std::tie(a, b) = returns_two();

  // a and b are now 1 and -1, no need to work with std::tuple accessors
  std::cout << "A" << a << std::endl;
}
```

Of course, in this case, you don't actually need to roll your own code to return the min and max of an input because there is a templated utility function that already does this, [`std::minmax`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/minmax) (for two discrete args and initializer lists) and [`std::minmax_element`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/minmax_element) (for ranges defined by iterators) (which both return `std::pair`, and `std::pair` is fully compatible with `std::tuple` of two elements).

Answer (score 1):

```
typedef struct {
    int a, b;
} tuple;

tuple example() {
    tuple ret = {1, 2};
    return ret;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Didn't think of structures at all.

Comment: This is the C solution, but it reinvents the wheel when C++ utility containers can do the same job without defining your own custom types explicitly.

Answer (score 1):

There are three possible scenario..

**Method 1** is using global array.

**Method 2** is using pointer.

**Method 3** is using structure.

You can't return multiple values from a C++ function by using variables. You can return only a data structure with multiple values, like a struct or an array.

Answer (score 0):

use `stl pair data type` for return two value or user define `struct data type` for return more value from a function.

Or you can return array from a function for multiple value.

There are so many ways.